# Lotus Notes: Open windows Folder using @formula or script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

i use this code to set doc field with directory address:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select destination folder", 0, "N:\") 
If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("arc_file",Cstr(objFolderItem.Path))   
End If
```

Is there a method to open the windows folder contained in the "arc_file" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Dim x As Integer
x=Shell("explorer /root, " & uidoc.FieldGetText("arc_file"),1)
```

Comment: it return "Unexpected: End of Line; excepted: expression" in that code line